# Open an existing form from the main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I designed two forms: `Form1` and `Form2`. `Form1` is the main form. There is a button in `Form1`, if I click the button, then `Form2` will pop out. I want to do something on `Form2`.

```
// click button in Form1.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form form2= new Form();
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

But `Form2` is a new form rather than an existing form.

It is wrong.

How? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating instance of Form class not the Form2 which you have in your project. Create instance of Form2 which you created earlier and then call ShowDialog in it.

You might have notice the in the program.cs something like Application.Run(new Form1()); Here we create the instance of Form1 and pass to Run method.

Do it this way by creating instance of Form2 and calling ShowDialog() method to show it

```
Form2 form2= new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: You have the Form2 class but not its instance. You might have notice the in the program.cs something like Application.Run(new Form1()); Here we create the instance of form1 and pass to Run method

Comment: Use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
Form2 form2= new Form2();
```

like  your class member and use it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        form2.ShowDialog(); //blocking call 

       //or form2.Show() //non blocking call
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on correct comments, to make this work instead of executing the `Close()` on the function which will lead to `Dispose()` you need to use `form2.Hide()` to make is simply *invisible*

Comment: This is making instance of Form not Form2

Comment: @Tigran This is wrong. After the first use if the user closed the form, then with the second call you will be accessing a disposed object.

Comment: if it closes yes, but you can hide it...will add this like an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You create blank form with

```
Form Form2= new Form();
```

You should use

```
Form2 form2= new Form2();
```

Complete code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2= new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputForm form1 = new InputForm();
            form1.Show();
        }
```

Here InputForm means which form you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

The question is "Open an existing form from the main form"

Okay lets change it a little, **Open an existing instance of form from the main form.**

when you **show a form**

```
new Form2().Show();
```

lets say you **hid** it using

```
Form2.Hide();
```

you guys *can* use this

```
var Form2_instance = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Single();
Form2_instance.Show();
```