# Jump form not working correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlconnection

It is a relevent question with [this previous one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448951/open-an-existing-form-from-the-main-form)

Bacasically I have two forms, I want to jump to the second form from the first form.
The code for the first form.

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Edit_Metric Edit_Metric = new Edit_Metric();
        Edit_Metric.Show();
    }

}
```

The second form:

```
public partial class Edit_Metric : Form
{
    BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private SqlDataAdapter da;
    public Edit_Metric()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QISConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    private void Edit_Metric_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgv.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
        DataGridViewButtonColumn EditColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        EditColumn.Text = "Edit";
        EditColumn.Name = "Edit";
        EditColumn.DataPropertyName = "Edit";
        EditColumn.DisplayIndex = 0;
        EditColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        DataGridViewButtonColumn DelColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        DelColumn.Text = "Delete";
        DelColumn.Name = "Delete";
        DelColumn.DataPropertyName = "Delete";
        DelColumn.DisplayIndex = 1;
        DelColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        dgv.Columns.Add(EditColumn);
        dgv.Columns.Add(DelColumn);

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connString"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // data query, display data in a datagridview.
        }
```

My question is: when the code reached

```
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connString"))
```

The next step code went to the first form immediately at

```
        Edit_Metric.Show();
```

It never goto the code in the second form

```
         conn.Open();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not a typo, your are trying to open a connection using the string "connString" instead of the var connString from the above "QISConnectionString"

I'm sure that you want to write

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
```